# Magento Referer url capture

Tags: magento

I am working with one Magento site i want to track user from where they came to the site and according to the source site i want to set the header of Magento and some calculation on site.

ie, site is `abc.com` and i have different 3 site. Like

1. pqr.com
2. xyz.com
3. def.com

So from `pqr.com` site user click link of `abc.com` so i want to track user based on source site.

I have some basic idea i can do using the referral url.

anybody guide on this topic.

Thanks.

Comment: try this. `$url = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];`

Comment: where i could wright this and how to keep track using session?

Comment: you could write this in index file and use cookies because session will lost once a user close you website. but by using cookie you can check whenever he came back

Comment: but only first time user arrive at a site at that time i am creating the cookie ? but are you sure the magento header will load based on cookie?

Comment: what exactly you want? just to track from which site user is referring, right?

Comment: thanks for your replying exactly what i am doing i am changing the header of magento site according to from where customer arraive, so in one controller i have created the cookie and in header.phtml file i checked the cookie and set the header but actually header is not set but when i refresh the same window it load the cookie and set header. it mean the cookie is not creating in properway.

Comment: yup, you can do that by cookie